# Push Notification through local parse-server and parse dash board

Tags: android, parse-server

Hi I am able to run parse-server and parse dashboard in my local system.I am trying to connect my android app to the parse -server which is also in same system.I am not hosting the parse-server to Heroku or any other Hosting site.I am able to get/send message from comandline using this command

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id:<App_ID>" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"Name":"<Name>","Score":<Score>}' \
 http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/Player
```

**But not able to connect the parse-server from my android app.**

mongodb,parse-server-example and parse-dashboard is properly working.My Android code :
**Manifest File**

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.parse.pushnotification" >

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
        <permission
                android:name="<my_Package>.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />        
       <uses-permission android:name="<my_Package>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />       

            <application
                android:name=".PushParseServerTest"
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

                <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>

 <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
            android:value="id:<gcm_project_id>" />

                <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

                <receiver
                    android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />                 

                        <category android:name="<my_package_name>" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <receiver
                    android:name="<my_package>.ParsePushnotificationReceiver"
                    android:exported="false" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />

                        <category android:name="<my_package_name>" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
            </application>    
        </manifest>
```

**Build.gradle file**

```
{

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
}
```

**PushParseServerTest.java**

```
public class StarterApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
   //Parse.initialize(this);

      Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
              .applicationId("@string/parse_app_id")
              .clientKey("@string/parse_client_key")
              .server("http://<my_system_ip>:1337/parse/")   // '/' important after 'parse'
              .build());    
  }
}
```

**ParsePushnotificationReceiver.java**

```
public class ParsePushnotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "ParsePushnotificationReceiver";
   // public static final String intentAction = "com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Receiver intent null");
        } else {
            // Parse push message and handle accordingly
            Log.d(TAG, intent.getExtras().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it an issue with push notifications or saving objects to parse-server?

Did you configure push notifications correctly on parse-server and register your android devices correctly?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer.yes I did configure parse-server correctly.As I mentioned I am able to get/send message from comandline using the said command.But I think registration of android device not happening with this api Parse.initialize(). Please let me know how to check the traffic in android app.

Comment: I'm no expert with Android at all, I may not be the best suited to help you here. From what I've seen, many people managed to get it working.

I suggest skim through the issues on https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/ and there will probably be a hint for the fix ;)